# The Shape Operator in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking to calculate the Shape operator, the second fundamental form, and the curvature tensor for the following:

$\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^1 = \{(w,x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^4 : y^2 + z^2 = 1 \}$

I have been struggling with finding a parametrization in the form I am familiar with, or even an orthogonal basis. All of the examples I have seen use $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: What's wrong with $(x, \sin \phi, \cos \phi)$? I think you must mean $R^3$ in your set builder notation - the space on the left is 2d and on the right is 3d.

Comment: @preferred_anon Huh? The space $\Bbb R^2\times S^1$ is most definitely a $3$-dimensional manifold. Anyhow, just do the parametrization you're used to for a cylinder in $\Bbb R^3$ and use $w$ as an extra (free) parameter. Both $w$ and $x$ will vary over all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @TedShifrin My brain's not working. I read $R^2 \times S^1$ and pictured a cylinder. My apologies.

Comment: @TedShifrin I understand the parametrization, and I found it quite straightforward to calculate $x_u = (-\sin u, \cos u, 0)$ and $x_v = (0, 0, 1)$. However my concern is with the basis $\{x_u, x_v\} \in \mathbb{R}^4$. I can treat $w$ as an extra parameter, but is it still valid for my basis vectors to only have 3 parameters? Or should I add an extra 0 onto both.

Comment: You need vectors $x_u$, $x_v$, $x_w$ in $\Bbb R^4$, of course.

Comment: @TedShifrin right that makes sense. But so then my parametrization is $x(u,v,w) = (\cos u, \sin u, v, w)$? Then I imagine that our normal becomes $N = \frac{x_u \wedge x_v \wedge x_w}{|x_u \wedge x_v \wedge x_w |}$. However, how does that effect the parameters $e,f, g$ of the second fundamental form? I imagine you need to introduce new parameters. However, I have never seen any documentation about this before, do you know where I could find a modified version of the Weingarten equations for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Your second fundamental form will now be a $3\times 3$ matrix.  I don't know any text that does specifically hypersurfaces in $\Bbb R^4$. Every graduate level differential geometry text will treat the topic of submanifolds of Riemannian manifolds. I would recommend that you proceed completely by analogy with surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ and not try to duplicate the classical notation of $E,F,G$ and $e,f,g$.

Comment: @TedShifrin through inference, it seems to me that the second fundamental form in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is calculated as $\begin{pmatrix} du & dv \end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}  du\\ dv \end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} du^2 & dudv\\   dudv & dv^2 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: It follows that I believe for $\mathbb{R}^4$ it should be calculated as $\begin{pmatrix}
  du & dv & dw
\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}
  du \\ 
  dv \\ dw
\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
  du^2 & dudv & dudw \\ 
  dvdu & dv^2 & dvdw \\ dwdu & dwdv & dw^2 
\end{pmatrix}$. Do you agree with this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. If you're going to represent the second fundamental form as an actual $2$-tensor, yes, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} e & f\\f & g\end{bmatrix}$ corresponds to $e\,du^2 + f(du\,dv+dv\,du) + g\,dv^2$. But I don't understand what you mean by "calculated as." You know $e=x_{uu}\cdot N$, etc. Do the analogous things with the third independent variable there.

Comment: To clarify, what I mean is that the second fundamental form in $\mathbb{R}^4$ should be expression as $e du^2 + 2f dudv + g dv^2 + 2h dudw + 2i dvdw + j dw^2 $, right?

Answer (score 0):

The outward pointing unit normal vector field to your surface is given by
$$
N(w,x,y,z) = (0,0,y,z).
$$
The shape operator $S$ is (up to the sign, depending on your convention)
$$
Sv = \nabla_vN.
$$
Can you go on from there?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Didier. Im unfamiliar with the notation, what is $v$ here? Additionally, do you believe a parametrization is necessary then?

Comment: @guillermo22 $v$ is a tangent vector.
I do believe that parametrizations are, most of the time, unnecessary, and that one can often deal without them (as I did).
As a side note, I think you should state what exactly you mean by shape operator: is this the endomorphism, the bilinear form (second fundamental form),or  the vector valued second fundamental form? How do you define it (it seems you have different notations than me)?

Comment: It's the Weingarten endomorphism associated to some $\xi$, where $\xi$ is some differentiable unit normal along $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{S}^1$

Comment: @guillermo22 So basically, it is exactly what I wrote above!